# Copying asset files to SD Card (file not found)?

Tags: ocr, android-sdcard, tesseract, file-copying

I'm trying to copy files for Tesseract to use and no matter how I try it keeps giving me filenot found exceptions.  I don't understand why because I have them in the assets folder. I tried it one way by copying the specific tessdata folder which wasn't working so I tried putting them all under the general assets folder and copying each file in there into a new directory I created on the card called tessdata.

Here's an image of the files in the folder, the method for copying and the log errors that post:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
    try {
        files = assetManager.list("");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
    }
    for(String filename : files) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
          in = assetManager.open(filename);
          out = new FileOutputStream(tesspath+ "/" + filename);
          copyFile(in, out);
          in.close();
          in = null;
          out.flush();
          out.close();
          out = null;
        } catch(IOException e) {
            android.util.Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
        }       
    }
}
```

-I also tried using this method from an example which copied them from the tessdata folder within assets-

```
if (!(new File(tesspath + File.separator + lang + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
        copyAssets();
        /* try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
            //open the asset manager and open the traineddata path
            InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/eng.traineddata");
            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "OPENED SUCCESSFULLY IF NO ERROR BEFORE THIS");
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tesspath + "/eng.traineddata");
            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "WRITING NOW  TO" + tesspath);
            byte[] buf = new byte[8024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Was unable to copy " + lang
                    + " traineddata " + e.toString());
            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "IM PRINTING THE STACK TRACEs");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        */
    } else {
        processImage(STORAGE_PATH + File.separator + "savedAndroid.jpg");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the sdcard write perssion in manifest.xml ? 
probably you will need this in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```